# Why is using regex alternation for a string of search words faster then a for-loop of search words in a list?

Tags: python, regex, performance

Why is the 1st python3.8.3 script that uses regex with key search words separated by a "|" (I believe alternation) ~ 13x faster than the 2nd python script that also uses regex but implements a For Loop to iterate through a list of search words?

Both scripts load the db_list and pos & neg variables in memory. Both scripts provide the exact same outcome for the word counts.

The 1st script has a runtime of about 26 seconds. The 2nd script takes about 5.5 minutes.

What is causing the in/efficiencies in either python or regex?

**1st Script**

```
db_list = 1,400,000 text comments from reddit loaded into a tuple of tuples

# 71 pos words and 71 negative words in their respective lists
pos_item = ['pos words', 'in', 'a', 'list', 'like this']
neg_item = ['neg words', 'in', 'a', 'list', 'like this']

posWordsEx = rf'\b(?:{"|".join(pos_item)})\b'
negWordsEx = rf'\b(?:{"|".join(neg_item)})\b'

for comment in db_list:
    word_search = re.findall(posWordsEx, comment[0])
    pos_count = pos_count + len(word_search)
    word_search = re.findall(negWordsEx, comment[0])
    neg_count = neg_count + len(word_search)
```

**2nd Script**

```
db_list = 1,400,000 text comments from reddit loaded into a tuple of tuples

# 71 pos words and 71 negative words in their respective lists
pos_item = ['pos words', 'in', 'a', 'list', 'like this']
neg_item = ['neg words', 'in', 'a', 'list', 'like this']

for comment in db_list:
    for pos_item in fpos_flist:
        word_search = re.findall(r"\b" + pos_item + r"\b", comment[0])
        pos_count = pos_count + len(word_search)

    for neg_item in fneg_flist:
        word_search = re.findall(r"\b" + neg_item + r"\b", comment[0])
        neg_count = neg_count + len(word_search)
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex that searches for one of a set of words can potentially be much faster than a naive looping approach.  How much depends on the regex implementation and the specific pattern.

[https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html](https://swtch.com/%7Ersc/regexp/regexp1.html)

A simple way to think about it without diving into the weeds of regex implementation is this: suppose you're trying to figure out if any of the words "hi", "hello", "hey", or "hola" are in a given string.

One approach would be to loop through the string four times -- does it contain "hi"?  does it contain "hello"?  does it contain "hey"?  does it contain "hola"?

A faster approach would be to recognize that all of those words start with "h", and begin your search by just looking for an "h" -- if you don't find one, you know that none of those words is in the string (and you only had to search through the entire string once instead of four times).  If you do find one, now you look to see if it's followed by any of "e", "i", or "o".  Et cetera.  This is more complex, but it's faster, and it's pretty close to what a state-machine regex implementation does.

Comment: Besides being based on a better algorithm, there's also the very real possibility that the module in the standard library was implemented in another much faster language like C.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the first script you're doing 2x less the loops/computations than in the second script. In the second script the first loop in the loop has to complete before the second one can start where as in the first script they happen simultaneously